# Searching a binary tree for a specific word

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I need to find a given word in a binary tree. I have this code

```
if (n !=null)
{
    if((name.compareTo(n.getVehicleName()) < 0) && n.left())
    {
        return find(name.hasLeft, n);
    }
    if((name.compareTo(n.getVehicleName()) > 0) && n.hasRight())
    {
        return find(name.right, n);
    }
    if(name.compareTo(n.getVehicleName()) == 0)
    {
        return Vehicle;
    }
}
```

I doesn't work and I'm not sure how to solve it.

The only help i was given was this:

```
* @param name  The name of the vehicle to search for
* @param n     The current node in the tree to search from
* @return      A reference to the node that was found or null if not found 

int order = name.compareTo(n.getVehicleName());

if(n==null) return null

return null;
```

Comment: "It doesn't work."

Whats the error? Whats the expected result? Just looking at your code, one potential problem is there is nothing to handle if you get to a leaf and the item you are looking for doesnt exist.

Comment: basically there is another method in a test class that will call 
Vehicle mf = manager.find("Concorde");
  if (mf != null) 
   System.out.println("Found: " + mf);
  else
   System.out.println("Could not find Concorde");

Comment: Is Concorde in the tree? You need to give more information or noone is going to be able to help you.

Comment: yea concorde is in the tree. the goal is to to create the search code to look through the binary tree for the word concorde which is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start you off by fixing some major problems and adding a case if you're at a leaf and still haven't found the word, where it returns null.

```
if (n != null)
{
    if(name.compareTo(n.getVehicleName()) < 0))
    {
        if(name.hasLeft()){
            return find(name.left, n);
        }else{
            return null
        }
    }
    else if((name.compareTo(n.getVehicleName()) > 0))
    {
        if(name.hasRight()){
            return find(name.right, n);
        }else{
            return null
        }
    }
    else if(name.compareTo(n.getVehicleName()) == 0)
    {
        return Vehicle;
    }
}
```

Comment: SO I altered the code to  and replaced the found returns with return n.getVehicle(); but when I run it (no errors) it  says it is found but when it prints the result it prints the wrong thing as it should print Concorde but it prints enzo (the first name in the binary tree)

Comment: Sounds like something wrong with the `find()` method. Edit your post to include it.